# MSBuild conditions based on imported properties

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a solution that has multiple projects, and I'd like them all to be able to access a set of shared properties that have been defined once in a common file at the solution level.

This mostly works fine using the code below and I can use the imported properties in the BeforeBuild target, however the problem I'm having is that I can't use the imported properties in conditions.

So I have the following in a CommonSettings.targets file in the solution folder:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="CommonSettingsTarget">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <MyCustomProperty>Sample</MyCustomProperty>
        </PropertyGroup>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

In my project file I have:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" InitialTargets="CommonSettingsTarget" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)CommonSettings.targets" />

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="EmbeddedDocument.txt" Condition=" '$(MyCustomProperty)' == 'Sample' " />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="MyCustomProperty='$(MyCustomProperty)'" Importance="high" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

In the above, I can see my imported property displayed in the output window as "MyCustomProperty='Sample'" which is great, however when it's used as part of a condition (to optionally include an embedded resource), the condition is never satisfied.

Is there any way to make the imported properties work with conditions?

Comment: Some other piece of advice: If you switch to VS 2017 / MSbuild 15, you can simply name the imported file `Directory.Build.props` and it will be imported automatically into all projects below that level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your `ItemGroup` is not within a target, but the `PropertyGroup` is, the `CommonSettingsTarget` has not yet been executed when your condition is evaluated and thus `MyCustomProperty` has not yet been defined.

The `Message` task is called from within the `BeforeBuild` target which depends on `CommonSettingsTarget` and thus `MyCustomProperty` has been defined when you create the message.

---

Think of the `Import` as copying the imported project into your project file. The result would be something like this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" InitialTargets="CommonSettingsTarget" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
   <Target Name="CommonSettingsTarget">
     <PropertyGroup>
       <MyCustomProperty>Sample</MyCustomProperty>
     </PropertyGroup>
   </Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="EmbeddedDocument.txt" Condition=" '$(MyCustomProperty)' == 'Sample' " />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="MyCustomProperty='$(MyCustomProperty)'" Importance="high" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

This is what happens:

1. You define a target `CommonSettingsTarget` which will define `MyCustomProperty` *when it is executed*. Not now.
2. You define the `ItemGroup` and therefore evaluate the condition. It returns `false`, because `MyCustomProperty` has not yet been defined.
3. You define a target `BeforeBuild`.
4. You run the initial target, i.e. `CommonSettingsTarget`. Now `MyCustomProperty` is defined.
5. You run the default target which depends on `BeforeBuild` and thus runs `BeforeBuild`. There you evaluate `MyCustomProperty` which has been defined in step 4.

---

As a solution, remove the `CommonSettingsTarget` target and define the `PropertyGroup` as a child of the `Project` in CommonSettings.targets instead:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <MyCustomProperty>Sample</MyCustomProperty>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

In your project file, you should remove the `InitialTargets="CommonSettingsTarget"` then.

Comment: Thanks for the info wkl.  It does work if I specifically define the properties in the project, however I've got a lot of projects within the solution that all need access to properties, and it would involve changing the values in each of the projects every time I need to adjust them.  I thought the InitialTargets on the Project itself might have done it but, it looks like the conditions are always evaluated before any imports?

Comment: I see what you mean now wkl.  It's importing and using my common properties perfectly now.  I was definitely over-complicating it with all those targets.  Thank you so much - I'll mark as answer :-)